depends on intl ^0.19.0, version solving failed
Because the app depends on form_builder_validators ^9.1.0 which depends on intl ^0.18.1, intl ^0.18.1 is required.
So, because app depends on intl ^0.19.0, version solving failed.

Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1
Build #AI-233.14808.21.2331.11709847, built on April 12, 2024

The above error occurs after the above update. What is the best solution?

Should I change form_builder_validators ^9.1.0 to another plugin?

form_builder_validators has a really poor pub points, so it might be a good idea to find another package. But if you really need it, you can use dependency overrides.

You can use dependency_overrides in this case if you really need that package. Check the image below
https://prnt.sc/pmbgYUueGd5O
